# Does it mean something special when all cofactors are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I came across a problem from an old qualifying exam involving a matrix $A$ wherein the entries of each column of $A$ sum to zero. The problem asked to prove things like: the matrix $A$ is singular, the cofactors of $A$ are all equal, and each column of the adjugate matrix is in the null space of $A$. The problem itself is similar to the problem proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406041/question-on-cofactors). My question is: Are such matrices of any special significance? Does this phenomenon appear often enough to have a name? Or is it just a cute trick that makes for an interesting qual problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It means either $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le n-2$ (where $A$ is $n\times n$) or all column sums and row sums of $A$ are zero.

Comment: @user1551 Yes, thank you for your reply. I meant: Is this a situation where one would say, "Ah yes! That is the classic zorganbop matrix that appears often in the context flergenstromer and has the special property that skipmadoo as discussed in chapters 3 through 7 of the text by Madeupname." Or is it just a contrived matrix that makes for a cute problem?

Comment: I would say it's the latter, since the condition concerns about two rather unrelated situations.

Comment: an example that fits the bill is the (typical) Laplacian Matrix